# SQL: Column Validation against GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I set a constraint to check whether the column have the value of `GETDATE()` or not. The column rule is to accept dates that are greater than or equal to `GETDATE()`.

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CONSTRAINT chk1 CHECK (date_column >= GETDATE ())
```

The problem is that, when I enter today's date into the column it gives an error indicating that it conflicts with the constraint otherwise if I enter tomorrow's date it accepts it.  It seems to be that the (= sign) is not working.

My question is: what is the problem and how it can be solved?

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you are entering in the column?

Comment: GETDATE() returns the current **DATE AND TIME** down to milliseconds, not the current **DATE**.  You're never going to hit the "=" sign because you can never predict, down to milliseconds, what the time will be when the database engine executes that call.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: You can't predict the current date & time? ;)

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you can't predict the *exact* date and time (down to milliseconds) when the GETDATE function is run by the engine.  But then I see you have ;) here...  :-)

Comment: @Stephen Chung: So specifying a date a minute/hour/etc in the future escapes you?  That's all the OP is asking for - that value won't always pass the test...

Comment: @OMG Ponies, the OP is not specifying a time.  Only a date.  Therefore time is automatically defaulted to midnight, 00:00.  Today's date at midnight is most likely going to be earlier than today's date with the current time (i.e. GETDATE).  That's why only his "tomorrow" date works and his "today" date doesn't work.

Comment: @Stephen Chung: That's your assumption, whereas the very first comment asks for clarification...

Comment: @OMG Ponies, true.  I made the assumption based on the OP saying he/she entered today's "date".

Answer (score 3):

If you are just entering today's date in the form mm/dd/yyyy that would evaluate to midnight for the current day. When you compare that to GetDate() it is evaluating to less than the current date and **time** You need to floor GetDate() to the start of the day.

Try using

```
cast(floor(cast(getdate() as float)) as datetime)
```

Comment: Casting to a float is not as reliable as using `DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()), 0)`, nor as fast.

Comment: True, but I always goof that up if I don't have SSMS handy, I just wanted to convey the idea. Your approach is the best that I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

Most practical I think would be changing the constraint to this (for the reasons others pointed out):

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD CONSTRAINT chk1 CHECK (date_column >= CAST(GETDATE() as date))
```

Optionally you also can change the type of your column from `datetime` to `date`

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that GETDATE() includes the current time as well.
Your constraint appears to allow any value thats GreaterThanOrEqualTo the current Datetime stamp for which the value is evaluated. Which I would think in this case would be anything in the future. I'd like to see your client code that compensates for this.
If your only looking to compare to the DATE then you need to change your constraint to the following.

CHECK (CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(10), date_column, 101)) => CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101)))

Here's a quick example:
SELECT GETDATE()
2011-04-26 20:39:11.240

SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 101))
2011-04-26 00:00:00.000

Answer (score 0):

GETDATE returns the current **DATE AND TIME** (down to milliseconds), **NOT** the current **DATE**.

SQL Server uses a Date-Time data type.  For dates only (without time information), the time is defaulted to midnight (i.e. 00:00).

If you input today's date WITHOUT A TIME, it will default to midnight (i.e. 00:00).  Today's date at midnight is always going to be earlier than GETDATE (which includes the current time).

Therefore your "today" date (midnight without time specificatoin) will never be >= GETDATE.  Tomorrow at midnight, though, works because it is later than GETDATE.

Experiment: Specify today's date, PLUS A TIME (say one hour later).  It should be accepted.